# Do I need an account or API key to use IPFS?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ipfs

I followed this [example](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/examples/browser-add-readable-stream), and it worked! Here's [my file](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmci4MUoKezwuEyoLbn7LbD8Z3mcyN6q2AHiT4Yp8srdKy). But I'm confused, why no API key and no account required?

Answer (score 1):

ipfs is for free cause it's aiming to grow a community for itself and it's aiming for voluntary-collaboration setting (such as p2p networks or academic research), or in the optimistic future in which IPFS replaces HTTP as the protocol that is synonymous with “the Internet” to most of the world.